# How to load an OLS model file (.pickle) from S3 bucket in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, statsmodels

I want to load a model file (.pickle) created by OLS from S3. here is my code:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import os
import statsmodels.api as sm

s3_r = boto3.resource("s3")
s3_c = boto3.client('s3')

model_file = 's3://mybucketpath/model.pickle'
model = sm.load(model_path)
```

But it didn't work. I  got an error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 's3:\\mybucketpath\\model.pickle'
```

What's more, I found my code is available if I load model files from a local path or CSV files from s3, like this:

```
model = sm.load('local_path/model.pickle')
print(model.summary())

df = pd.read_csv('s3:\\mybucketpath/data.csv')
print(df.head())
```

I don't know how to fix this problem and cannot find an online solution to this error

Comment: Loading things from s3 requires support for this protocol.  Statsmodels only supports local files at the moment. Extending the `load` and `save` to other protocols could be done.  You could also monkey patch the `load` function with one that supports `s3` then all you would have to do is install your monkey patch and all would go through.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question and now I want to share my solution.

According to Kevin S, the reason for the issue is that "Statsmodels only supports local files" so, loading model files from an online bucket is impossible.

My solution is to download files first and then load files locally. Here is my code:

```
# for example, my model file is saved in this path 'my_bucket/model/model.pickle', and I want to save it as myfirstmodel.pickle in my local machine

bucket_name = 'my_bucket' # your_buckect_name
model_path = 'model/model.pickle' # file_path
saved_name = 'myfirstmodel.pickle'

s3_r = boto3.resource("s3")
s3_r.meta.client.download_file(bucket_name, model_path, saved_name)
model = sm.load(saved_name)
```